# What to do about "does not always return formatted value" error?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

When attempting to add text containing Expression Language to a layout, I encounter an error that reads "Expression doesn't always return formatted value..."

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the Expression Language (EL) snippet with the `number()` EL function to explicitly define the format in which the value should be displayed.

[Here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/el-ref#formatting-functions) is a link to the documentation that provides more information on formatting functions.